# Does Istio gateway support specifying jwt_uri realm dynamically from request header or other request info?

Tags: istio

Found this documentation, https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authentication/authn-policy/#end-user-authentication, which discusses how to do JWT token validation at the gateway, and I have a fee questions regaring this:

Is there a way to specify the jwt_uri with like a templated value, where the value gets filled in by the value of a header that you specify or other information in the request? If so can you point me to any examples? The use case here is that we have multiple tenants, and we need to validate the token in a request for a given tenant against the keys for that respective tenant, which is retreived from jwt_uri path that includes tenant (realm) in uri path.

Can we specify a different jwt_uri per path? If so can you point me to any examples?

Are the keys retrieves from the jwt_uri cached? If so how do we control the caching?

Comment: Have you seen this[ istio documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/jwt/)? There are 2 examples with `jwtHeaders` and `audiences`. Could you check it and let me know if that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to specify the jwt_uri with like a templated value, where the value gets filled in by the value of a header that you specify or other information in the request?

I checked in the [istio in action book](https://livebook.manning.com/book/istio-in-action/chapter-8/v-7/322) and seems like it's possible. Take a look at below example.

```
apiVersion: "security.istio.io/v1beta1"
kind: "RequestAuthentication"
metadata:
 name: "jwt-token-request-authn"
 namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: istio-ingressgateway
 jwtRules:
 - issuer: "auth@istioinaction.io"
   jwks: |
     { "keys": [{"e":"AQAB","kid":"##REDACTED##","kty":"RSA","n":"##REDACTED##"}]}
```

As I mentioned in comments there is [istio documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/jwt/) about jwt.

---

> Can we specify a different jwt_uri per path? If so can you point me to any examples?

I checked in [older documentation](https://istio.io/v1.4/docs/tasks/security/authentication/authn-policy/#disable-end-user-authentication-for-specific-paths) and it was possible to do with Policy, I checked [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/15868#issuecomment-519294428) and now it should be possible to achieve with AuthorizationPolicy and RequestPolicy.

Take a look at below documentation links:

- https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/request_authentication/
- https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/
- https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/conditions/

---

> Are the keys retrieves from the jwt_uri cached? If so how do we control the caching?

Quoted from [envoy documentation](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/config/filter/http/jwt_authn/v2alpha/config.proto)

> **cache_duration**
>
> (Duration) Duration after which the cached JWKS should be expired. If not specified, default cache duration is 5 minutes.

I'm not sure if it can be set up in istio, there is [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/10547) about that, there is no answer so far.